# LeanFT license status when JAR file is executed

Tags: hp-uft, hp-alm, leanft

How could `LeanFT` check licensing status, when JAR file is generated from a `LeanFT` project and executed without use of an IDE? In this case `LeanFT` runtime engine isn't started and URL of license server is not stored in jar file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LeanFT is more than just that `.jar` file, and the engine logic takes place somewhere else. Roughly, LeanFT consists of two main parts:

1. **LeanFT client**

   - is the SDK with all the tests. In your case, a `.jar` file, but could've been a `.cs` or `.js` test and would have acted just the same.
   - has code like `Browser.launch` and `Element.click`.
   - these are commands that are sent to the LeanFT engine
2. **LeanFT engine**

   - among others, is a websocket server that listens to commands, interprets and executes them

The whole journey a command makes is roughly something as follows:

1. `LFT.init` is executed somewhere in the code.

   - It initiates the connection with **the right** socket server, configured either in a properties file (for java, it is `leanft.properties` file), or at runtime, via a configuration object (for java, it is a `ModifiableSDKConfiguration` object). Some *minimal* guidance regarding this configuration can be found [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/CustomFrameworks.htm)
   - this server can be on any computer on the accessible network, but the engine must be there too! (there are a lot of details regarding this [here](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/leanft/en/14.03/HelpCenter/Content/HowTo/RunRemotely.htm))
   - Without this command, the test will fail because any command (like `click`) can't execute as there is no WS connection
2. `Element.click` is executed somewhere later in the code
3. SDK constructs and sends a message to the engine (through websocket connection)
4. The engine checks if it has a valid license and if all good it performs the command.

Visualized, it is something like this:

[image]

Comment: Could you please put also ALM to your figure?

Comment: Well, if I'm not mistaken, ALM is not part of the figure, it's just a kind of CI tool that downloads the resources (`.jar` file for example) and triggers the execution, which then leads to the same figure, be it ALM, jenkins or manual execution